# Can we have multivalored attributes related to a two-column primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, composite-key, multivalue

I'm working on a Java project that has a Database developed in MySQL software, and this job consists on having an entity identified by two columns, named `CPF` and `ID`.

This entity has some multivalored attributes, like `CELLPHONE`, and as usual, I'm creating a new table for multivalored attributes, using the `PRIMARY KEY(ID,CPF)` identification, so we can relate the tables between them.

However, I'm not able to create multiple rows in my `CELLPHONE` table, and MySQL warns me `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'CPF' for key 'cellphones.CPF'`.

In summary, I'm trying to use a two-column primary key to identify an entity, and using this primary key to create a multivalored attribute table, but I'm not having success.

I'm leaving below my code referring to the entity where I create the two-column primary key (PESSOA) and the code referring the multivalored table I'm trying to create (TELEFONES--the CELLPHONE I mentioned above).

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA(
CPF                     VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ID                      BOOL NOT NULL,
NOME                    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
SEXO                    BOOL,
FOTO                    BLOB,
SALDO_BANCARIO          DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(ID,CPF)
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONES(
CPF                     VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ID                      BOOL NOT NULL,
NUMERO                  VARCHAR(15),

FOREIGN KEY (ID,CPF) REFERENCES PESSOA(ID,CPF) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: The term is "multivalued" or "multi-valued". But what exactly do you think a multivalued attribute is? And a multivalued attribute table? Why is CELLPHONE multivalued? PS Debug questions require a [mre]. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. [ask] [Help] PS Read re constraints & indexes in the manual, column order must sometimes agree with CREATE.

Comment: What thing/entity does each ID identify? What subrow in what table has multiple values for each value of what subrow in what table? You are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple row in cellphone table then you can't add primary key on multiple field. You have to remove primary key from TELEFONES and make both row indexed. Because of two row primary key it will not accept ID and CPF duplicate row again.